# How do i make an image change multiple colors of tags using .css in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

How do I make an image use mousedown and mouseup to make .css in Jquery change multiple functions of Html?

This is what I have:

```
$(document).mousedown(function() {
    $('body').css({ color: 'yellow' });
    $('p').css({ color: 'yellow' });
});
$('body').css({ color: 'red' });
$('p').css({ color: 'pink' });
});
});
```

Comment: what do you want to do? chaging image ? or changing color?

Comment: What image are you talking about? Your code runs when you click anywhere on the document.

Comment: You also have some extra `});` at the end of your posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that can help you : https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/3kw65ssk/

You have several syntax errors, and you are missing `mouseup` event

```
$(document).mousedown(function(){
    $('body').css({color: 'yellow'});
    $('p').css({color: 'yellow'});
}).mouseup(function(){
    $('body').css({color: 'red'});
    $('p').css({color: 'pink'});
});
```